# Rendering JSON data to HTML tags

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I would like to put data on my weather station website that I download from the API created by this station. It is a JSON file that has the following data structure:

```
data
    outdoor
        temperature
            unit:℃
            value:-0.2

    dew_point
            unit:℃
            value:-1.5
    humidity
            unit:%
            value:91
    rainfall
        rain_rate
            unit:mm/hr
            value:0.0
        daily
            unit:mm
            value:4.2

etc. for other parameters
```

I download it all by code

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('LINK TO API');
$data = json_decode($json)->data;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

I would like to know how I can separate these (maye in html tags?) and show them on my weather page. The way is arbitrary, I have a void in my head and I can't handle it alone

Part of the template from my website looks like this:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 20%"><span style="font-size:25px"><i class="wi wi-thermometer" title="Temperature"></i></span></td>
        <td style="padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 20%"><span style="font-size:25px"><i class="wi wi-raindrop" title="Dew point"></i></span></td>
        <td style="padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 20%"><span style="font-size:25px"><i class="wi wi-humidity" title="Humidity"></i></span></td>
        <td style="padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 20%"><span style="font-size:25px"><i class="wi wi-strong-wind" title="Wind gust"></i></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 20%"><span style="font-size:20px"><b>    </b></span></td>
        <td style="padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 20%"><span style="font-size:20px"><b>    </b></span></td>
        <td style="padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 20%"><span style="font-size:20px"><b>    </b></span></td>
        <td style="padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 20%"><span style="font-size:20px"><b>    </b></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `print_r()` is not efficient for that. Use a foreach loop, or look at any modern template library.

Comment: Okay, but how do I do it so that I can display the data in the template? As you can see, it needs a minimum of 4 values. Temperature, Dew Point, Humidity and Wind Gust. Minimum insert 4x file get contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would been easier for people if you had given them the link to the [API](https://doc.ecowitt.net/web/#/apiv3en?page_id=17). It's got the JSON response.

The response is somewhat complex, hence your question. I'll do only the data which fits in your template:

```php-template
<?php

$json    = file_get_contents('LINK TO API');
$data    = json_decode($json)->data;
$outdoor = $data->outdoor;
$wind    = $data->wind;

function output($measurement)
{
    echo $measurement->value . $measurement->unit;
}

?>
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 20%"><span style="font-size:25px"><i class="wi wi-thermometer" title="Temperature"></i></span></td>
        <td style="padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 20%"><span style="font-size:25px"><i class="wi wi-raindrop" title="Dew point"></i></span></td>
        <td style="padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 20%"><span style="font-size:25px"><i class="wi wi-humidity" title="Humidity"></i></span></td>
        <td style="padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 20%"><span style="font-size:25px"><i class="wi wi-strong-wind" title="Wind gust"></i></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 20%"><span style="font-size:20px"><b><?php  output($outdoor->temperature); ?></b></span></td>
        <td style="padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 20%"><span style="font-size:20px"><b><?php  output($outdoor->dew_point); ?></b></span></td>
        <td style="padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 20%"><span style="font-size:20px"><b><?php  output($outdoor->humidity); ?></b></span></td>
        <td style="padding: 8px;text-align: center;width: 20%"><span style="font-size:20px"><b><?php  output($wind->wind_gust); ?></b></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can you continue this yourself now?

Note that this code is untested, so I cannot guarantee it will work properly.

Comment: Yes, thats working. Thank you very much :)
I didn't provide a link because has a MAC adress for statilon...;)